# How to save ADF file in Unity

Tags: google-project-tango

In the Unity demo,how to save the ADF file?

I don't know if the `AreaDesription.SaveCurrent()` function use for do it and I don't know why the following code's position and rotation data is specified not get runtime.

using

```
(StreamWriter streamWriter = 
       new StreamWriter(File.Open(EMULATED_ADF_SAVE_PATH + uuid + EMULATED_ADF_EXTENSION,
                                  FileMode.Create)))
{
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    metadata.m_name = "Unnamed";
    metadata.m_dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    metadata.m_transformationPosition = new double[3];
    metadata.m_transformationRotation = new double[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    metadataXmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter, metadata);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Unity Example here (AreaDescriptionManagement)](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoSDK/Examples/AreaDescriptionManagement/Scripts/ADMGUIController.cs#L590) which shows a full example of [Saving Area Descriptions](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/unity/reference/class/tango/area-description#savecurrent), and also editing them etc...
I'd recommend running that example, and then ripping out the bits you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!             I have already run this example，the position and rotation information has always been the data in the function and can modified on the GUI.But I don't know why the data not get in realtime?